# iOS/UIKit: Keep size during rotation

Tags: ios, uikit, interface-builder

I am trying to have a `UIView` centered at the middle of the screen that is 320x240 when the device is in the landscape orientation and 240x320 when in the portrait orientation.

For example:

[image: Portrait Mode]
[image: Landscape Mode]

---

If I let UIKit's layout system do it on its own, I get this when rotating landscape:

[image: Bad Landscape 1]

And if I try to pin the width and height, I get this:

[image: Bad Landscape 2]

---

Basically, is there any way to **keep the dimensions of an object during a rotation** (but still rotate the object)? Preferably using only Interface Builder, and/or a minimal amount of code if that is not possible.

Comment: But your goal is *not* to keep the size. Your goal is to *change* the size from 320x240 to 240x320.

Comment: Good point, I didn't quite know how to word it correctly.

Comment: Have you tried tying into the orientation delegate methods from your view controller?  From there, you can resize your subview based on the orientation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I can but I'm wondering if there's a way to do it using autolayout/constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I think JeffCompton is right: there is no way for you to *change* the size of your view given the orientation using just the XIB / Autolayouts / Autoresizing masks.

I think the simplest way to do that is:

```
- (void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^(void) {
        if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation])) {
            self.yourView.frame = CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].frame.size.width-320/2,[UIScreen mainScreen].frame.size.height-240/2,320,240);
        } else {
            self.yourView.frame = CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].frame.size.width-240/2,[UIScreen mainScreen].frame.size.height-320/2,240,320);
        }
    }];
}
```